# NSPredicate issue with greater than equals

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a simple NSPredicate which is not giving correct result

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.data.squareFootage >= %@", filterSquareFootage];
filteredArray = [[filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
```

Strangely this works for all 6000>=250, 7000>=250, 8000>=6000. But as soon as squareFootage==10000 the predicate for 10000>=any smaller value is false. 
Note: 10000 for squareFootage is a max value fetched using a UISlider.If i reduce value to any smaller value, the predicate gives true as result

Am i missing something here and using predicate incorrectly?

Comment: How are you storing the values (what data type, number / string / ...) ?

Comment: @Wain - squarefootage is stored as an NSString in a model class conforming to NSCoding.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I assume that your property is stored as *string* and not as *number*, therefore
the values are compared as strings:

```
"10000" < "250" < "6000"
```

Using `NSNumber` instead of `NSString` (or alternatively some scalar type as `NSInteger`) should fix the problem.

If you cannot change the data type of the `squareFootage` property, then the following
predicate should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.data.squareFootage.intValue >= %d", [filterSquareFootage intValue]]
```

Comment: i changed squarefootage and filtersquarefootage to NSNumber with placeholder in predicate still as %@. But now the call to filteredArrayUsingPredicate is raising an [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance exception. Any ideas what going wrong here.

Comment: @basstrekekr87: This would happen if any of the `squareFootage` values is still a NSString and not a NSNumber.

Comment: The .intValue inside the predicate format really helps.

Comment: @MartinR how does String comparison work here. Its simple to understand if the string characters fall in the ascii range. Assuming Swift internally store string using utf8 or utf16 how does the comparison work for multiple byte characters codepoints?

Answer (score 0):

**YOU CAN"T COMPARE STRINGS USING =<** . if SELF.data.squareFootage is a NSNumber try converting filterSquareFootage to NSnumber or int value and compare them like that.

Comment: i did convert both squareFootage and filterSquareFootage to NSNumber(placeholder in predicate is %@ for NSNumber) but now filteredArrayUsingPredicate is giving an [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.